# How to add edges between set of vertices which are populated by using like search using GremlinPipeLine in java

Tags: java, titan, gremlin

I want to filter two sets of vertices by using like search and then i want to add edges between these vertices if a property eg. `location` matches .

- Step 1: Do like search using mgrNo like starts with 100
- Step 2:
  Do like search using mgrNo like starts with 200
- Step 3:Add edge
  between the vertices generated by step 1 and 2 if a property say for
  eg. `location` of vertex A and vertex B matches.

**I would like to know how to do this in java using `gremlinPipeLine`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you really need complex Gremlin to do this:

```
// using some groovy for simplicity note that this is graph query syntax 
// and not a "pipeline". to convert to java, you will just need to iterate
// the result of vertices() into an ArrayList and convert the use of 
// each{} to foreach or some other java construct 
mgr100 = g.query().has("mgrNo",CONTAINS_PREFIX,"100").vertices().toList()
mgr200 = g.query().has("mgrNo",CONTAINS_PREFIX,"200").vertices().toList()

mgr100.each {
    mgr200.findAll{x -> x.location == it.location}.each{x -> it.addEdge('near', x)}
}
```

Note use of some Titan-specific syntax around [CONTAINS_PREFIX](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/search-predicates.html).  While you could probably try to convert this code into a Gremlin Pipeline somehow, i'm not so sure that it would be that much more readable than this.

Comment: Hi @stephen , I have implemented using the above technique only . But just wanted to know if there is any other way of doing this using a query as we are performing the third step via the code , it takes considerable amount of memory and time right ?

Comment: How much time/memory it takes is dependent on the size of your data I guess.  I didn't assume that you had any restrictions there in providing my answer.  You could convert one of the queries that gets the "mgrNo" vertices to a pipeline to lazily evaluate it (rather than using `toList()`).  Then, if you have a more efficient way to query on "location" (perhaps it is an indexed property) you could query the other managers for each manager of the first query.  That could be faster and nicer to memory, but, as I said earlier, I guess that depends on your schema and data size.

Comment: Yeah. That seems to be a possibe solution